# How to reuse traceId from incoming request?

Tags: trace, micronaut

I want to trace spans across multiple services, but I don't know how to reuse/import incoming traceId. If I use @NewSpan annotation, it generates a new traceId, if it is first in the request.
If there is a traceId, the @NewSpan reuses it, but only inside one application.

I have tried to preset request headers and attributes, but no luck.

Comment: how are you calling the other services ?, over the paper micronaut will propagate automatically the trace context if thats in the configuration and the dependent services are invoked over http/grpc/kakfa, if you have the required dependencies in your classpath

Comment: First the headers are not propagated to response. I have the io.micronaut.tracing:micronaut-tracing-opentelemetry-http dependency. Second, the headers are not consumed and the trace Id is not "imported" from request headers.

Comment: I use X-B3 headers to propagate the trace id in requests